# Find The Parity Outlier Python

Tags: python

```
def find_outlier(lstOfints):
  for integer in lstOfints:
    #print(integer)
    if integer % 2 ==1:
      integer
    elif integer % 2 == 0:
      integer
  return integer
```

I keep getting the incorrect answer and I don't know what's going on.
This is the problem:

> You are given an array (which will have a length of at least 3, but could be very large) containing integers. The array is either entirely comprised of odd integers or entirely comprised of even integers except for a single integer N. Write a method that takes the array as an argument and returns this "outlier" N.

Comment: you have to use `return`

Comment: you have to use `return` after `for`-loop - after you check all values and you find `N`

Comment: The instructions imply that you need to look at more than one item in the sequence in order to determine which specific one is the outlier. You're just returning the first one.

Comment: Is it correct now? I put a return after checking if the integer is odd or even

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do? What does your list look like? What should the outlier be returned as?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the Parity Outlier in a list of odd/even integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39089459/finding-the-parity-outlier-in-a-list-of-odd-even-integers)

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work for me:

```
def find_outlier(lstOfints):
    if lstOfints[0] % 2 == 1 and lstOfints[1] % 2 == 1:
        for integer in lstOfints[2::]:
            if integer % 2 == 0:
                return integer
    elif lstOfints[0] % 2 == 0 and lstOfints[1] % 2 == 0:
        for integer in lstOfints[2::]:
            if integer % 2 == 1:
                return integer
    else:
        if lstOfints[0] % 2 == lstOfints[2] % 2:
            return lstOfints[1]
        else:
            return lstOfints[0]
```

Firstly, I am seeing if this list is either all odds, or all evens, bar the outlier. Then if it is even, it goes through the list looking for an odd number, the same for if the list is all odd. However, if the outlier is in the first two numbers, then it checks to see whether the outlier is the first number or the second number by comparing the modulos to the modulo of the third number in the list.

Comment: The problem says, "which will have a length of at least 3, but could be very large". Does your only check the first three?

Comment: It checks the first two numbers to see whether they are either even or odd or mixed. If they are the same then it checks the rest of the list for an outlier. However, if they are different, then it compares them with the third number, to see which is the outlier, as the question says that there is only one outlier in the entire list.

Comment: Right. The list will be "at least 3". There could be 4, 5, 6+. You want to code for that as well.

Comment: Exactly. That is what the for loops are for in the first if and elif statements

Comment: He's using for loops to avoid hard coding so everything is nice and automated

Comment: Gotcha. I see now!

Answer (score 1):

A pythonic answer might be something like that:

```
def find_outlier(lst):
  mods = [n % 2 for n in lst]
  return lst[mods.index(0)] if sum(mods[:3]) > 1 else lst[mods.index(1)]

print(find_outlier([5, 31, 57, 45, 9, 17, 8, 37, 123, 67])) # --> 8

print(find_outlier([4, 30, 56, 44, 8, 16, 7, 36, 122, 66])) # --> 7
```

**Explanation:** first create the list of all `n % 2` for all `n` in the provided list. Then you simply have to check the sum of the first 3 elements of this new list to know whether the outlier is odd or even. Then find index of the outlier remainder (either 0 or 1) and return the corresponding integer from the first list...

Answer (score 0):

There are many things to change in your code, so I will try to change it at steps to get it working at the end.

## Run the function from the question

Well, I tested your code here and I see why it is confusing. I have this script:

```
def find_outlier(lstOfints):
  for integer in lstOfints:
    #print(integer)
    if integer % 2 ==1:
      integer
    elif integer % 2 == 0:
      integer
  return integer

print(find_outlier([1,3,4,5]))
print(find_outlier([1,2,3,4]))
```

...and if I run it, we get this:

```
$ python disparity.py
5
4
```

It is just printing the last number! Why so?

## Why is it always printing the last number from the list?

Well, because you just return at the end of the function. You expect the function to return from inside the `if` statement, but you did not used the `return` command. It is easy to solve:

```
def find_outlier(lstOfints):
  for integer in lstOfints:
    if integer % 2 ==1:
      return integer
    elif integer % 2 == 0:
      return integer
  return integer

print(find_outlier([1,3,4,5]))
print(find_outlier([0,2,3,4]))
```

So now we run it and get

```
$ python disparity.py
1
0
```

Now it is just returning the *first* element!

## Why is it now always printing the *first* number from the list?

It prints the first element because your `if` statements are complementary. Given *any* element, regardless of its parity, it modulo 2 will be either 0 or 1. If it is zero, the first `if` returns; if it is `1`, the second returns! Since it is true to *all* elements, it is true to the first one, so the function ends at the very first iteration.

This is not the algorithm you want. What you want is to *first* know which parity is the outlier, and *then* look for the outlier number.

## How to discover which parity is an outlier if I don't know which number is the outlier?

Since the list has at least three elements, that is easy: we consider two scenarios.

- The first scenario is, the outlier is one of the first three elements. In this case, we will have one outlier parity and two "normal" parities.
  [image: An array containing the numbers 1 4 5 3 7 11 and 9. Notice that all numbers are odd except for 4, and that 4 is one of the first three values in the array.]
- The second scenario is, the outlier is *not* one of the first three elements. In this case, we will have three equal parities, and the outlier will be the opposite one. [image: An array containing the numbers 1 3 5 7 11 4 and 9. Notice that all numbers are odd except for 4, and that 4 is *not* one of the first three values in the array.]

So, if we count the number of even numbers and odd numbers in the first three values, we know that the parity with less numbers is the outlier one.

- If there are more even numbers than odd numbers (either two even and one odd, or three even and no odd), then we know the outlier is odd.
- If there are more odd numbers than even numbers, we know the outlier is even.

## Now, how to do it in code?

To do that, I will write pieces of code below that, at then end, put together, will give us the answer. First I create two variables to count the even and odd numbers (with 0 at first).

```
  even_numbers = 0
  odd_numbers = 0
```

Then, I see if the first element is even. If so, I increment the counter of even numbers:

```
  if listOfints[0] % 2 == 0:
      even_numbers = even_numbers + 1
  else:
      odd_numbers = odd_numbers + 1
```

Then I do the same thing with the second and third elements:

```
  if listOfints[1] % 2 == 0:
      even_numbers = even_numbers + 1
  else:
      odd_numbers = odd_numbers + 1

  if listOfints[2] % 2 == 0:
      even_numbers = even_numbers + 1
  else:
      odd_numbers = odd_numbers + 1
```

If we have more even numbers than odd numbers, we know the outlier parity is odd (that is, the rest of the division of the outlier to 2 is 1); if we have more odd numbers than even numbers, the outlier parity will be even (that is, the rest will be zero)

```
  if even_numbers > odd_numbers:
      outlier_parity = 1
  else:
      outlier_parity = 0
```

## So, now I know if the outlier number is even or odd, I agree. But I want to know what is the number!

Now that we *do know* the parity of the outlier, we just need to look for it:

```
  for integer in lstOfints:
    if integer % 2 == outlier_parity:
      return integer
```

Bundling all together, this is our new function:

```
def find_outlier(lstOfints):
  even_numbers = 0
  odd_numbers = 0

  if lstOfints[0] % 2 == 0:
      even_numbers = even_numbers + 1
  else:
      odd_numbers = odd_numbers + 1

  if lstOfints[1] % 2 == 0:
      even_numbers = even_numbers + 1
  else:
      odd_numbers = odd_numbers + 1

  if lstOfints[2] % 2 == 0:
      even_numbers = even_numbers + 1
  else:
      odd_numbers = odd_numbers + 1

  if even_numbers > odd_numbers:
      outlier_parity = 1
  else:
      outlier_parity = 0


  for integer in lstOfints:
    if integer % 2 == outlier_parity:
      return integer

print(find_outlier([1,3,4,5]))
print(find_outlier([0,2,3,4]))
```

Does it work? Let's test:

```
$ python disparity.py
4
3
```

Oh, it worked! Not bad, right? :)

## Some considerations

This code here isn't the most elegant, but my purpose here is mostly that you understand what is going on. It could be done with a waaaaaay shorter, more readable function, but since you are still looking for basic concepts, I did a more detailed, explainable function, which is kind of cumbersome as a consequence.

Answer (score 0):

my solution is:

```
def find_outlier(integers):
    odd = []
    even = []
    for i in integers:
        if i% 2 != 0:
            odd.append(i)
        elif i% 2 == 0:
            even.append(i)
    if len(odd) < len(even):
        return odd[0]
    else:
        return even[0]
```